# mongoDB search records by multidimensional array

Tags: mongodb, multidimensional-array, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I've been trying to figure out how to return results from mongoDB that match an array (key value pair) inside another array. Take this example in mongo.

```
{
    "_id" : NumberLong(19),
    "_t" : "OsmNode",
    "uname" : "Robert Whittaker",
    "uid" : 84263,
    "version" : 3,
    "changeset" : 1.40583e+007,
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2012-11-27T12:38:46.000Z"),
    "tags" : [ 
        [ 
            "ref", 
            "SG4 90"
        ], 
        [ 
            "amenity", 
            "post_box"
        ], 
        [ 
            "box_type", 
            "lamp_box"
        ], 
        [ 
            "collection_times", 
            "Mo-Fr 16:30; Sa 09:45"
        ]
    ],
    "tagKeys" : [ 
        "ref", 
        "amenity", 
        "box_type", 
        "collection_times"
    ],
    "location" : [ 
        51.9458770751953130, 
        -0.2069800049066544
    ]
}
```

The tags field contains multiple key-value pairs. What I want to do is return all records that contains an "amenity" key and value of "post_box". Doing something like this

```
db.getCollection('nodes').find(
    {
        "tags": [ [ 
            "amenity", 
            "post_box"
        ] ]
    }
)
```

Unfortunately the above only returns records that have a single tag which is "amenity", "post_box". So because the above record contains "ref", "box_type", "collection_times" tags as well as the amenity tag it isn't returned in the query results. Looking around on Google I've found many examples of arrays but not an array that contains another array. I think I need to use $in or £elemMatch but trying those I cannot seem to get them to play ball with the above.

Comment: Are "amenity" and "post_box" always in the same array?

Comment: Yes always in the same array. So in the tags array is one or more arrays of key value pairs so the first element is the key amenity which has a value post_box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your current documents structure you need to use the [`$all`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) operator

```js
db.collection.find( { 'tags': { '$all': [ [ 'amenity', 'post_box' ] ] } } )
```

But note that the order of elements in the sub-array matter for example the following query will not return any document.

```js
db.collection.find( { 'tags': { '$all': [ [ 'post_box', 'amenity' ] ] } } )
```

And so as workaround you will need to use the [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#op._S_or) operator

```js
db.collection.find( { 
    '$or': [ 
        { 'tags': { '$all': [ [ 'post_box', 'amenity' ] ] } }, 
        { 'tags': { '$all': [ [ 'amenity', 'post_box' ] ] } } 
    ] 
} )
```

So the best thing to do here is to change your documents structure. To do that you need to iterate the  [cursor](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/cursors/) and for update each document using ["bulk"](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/Bulk/) operations for efficiency.

```js
db.collection.find().forEach(function(doc) {
    var tags = doc.tags.map(function(element) {
        return { 'tagsKeys': element[0], 'value': element[1] }; 
    });
    bulk.find({'_id': doc._id}).updateOne({
        '$set': {'tags': tags}, 
        '$unset': {'tagKeys': ''} 
    }); 
    count++; 
    if(count % 250 === 0) { 
        // Execute per 250 operations and re-init    
        bulk.execute();     
        bulk = db.test.initializeOrderedBulkOp(); 
    } 
})
// Clean up queues
if(count > 0) bulk.execute()
```

Your document look like this:

```js
{
        "_id" : NumberLong(19),
        "_t" : "OsmNode",
        "uname" : "Robert Whittaker",
        "uid" : 84263,
        "version" : 3,
        "changeset" : 14058300,
        "timestamp" : ISODate("2012-11-27T12:38:46Z"),
        "tags" : [
                {
                        "tagsKeys" : "ref",
                        "value" : "SG4 90"
                },
                {
                        "tagsKeys" : "amenity",
                        "value" : "post_box"
                },
                {
                        "tagsKeys" : "box_type",
                        "value" : "lamp_box"
                },
                {
                        "tagsKeys" : "collection_times",
                        "value" : "Mo-Fr 16:30; Sa 09:45"
                }
        ],
        "location" : [
                51.94587707519531,
                -0.2069800049066544
        ]
}
```

Then your query become more simpler:

```js
db.collection.find({'tags.tagsKeys': 'amenity', 'tags.value': 'post_box'})
```

Now if "tagKey" is not always the first element in the "tags" subarray then you will need to use the [`.aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate) method which  provides access to the [aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/).

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": { 
        "element": { 
            "$map": {
                "input": "$tags", 
                "as": "tag", 
                "in": {
                    "value": { "$setDifference": [ "$$tag", "$tagKeys" ] }, 
                    "key": { "$setIntersection": [ "$$tag", "$tagKeys" ] } 
                }
            }
        }
    }}, 
    { "$unwind": "$element" }, 
    { "$unwind": "$element.key" }, 
    { "$unwind": "$element.value" }, 
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": "$_id", 
        "tags": {
            "$push": {
                "tagKey": "$element.key", 
                "value": "$element.value"
            }
        }
    }}
]).forEach(function(doc) {
    bulk.find( { '_id': doc._id } ).updateOne( {
        '$set': { 'tags': doc.tags }, 
        '$unset': { 'tagKeys': '' }
    }); 
    count++; 
    if(count % 200 === 0) { 
        // Execute per 200 operations and re-init
        bulk.execute();     
        bulk = db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp(); 
    } 
})

// Clean up queues
if(count > 0) bulk.execute()
```

**Now what is going on in our pipeline?**

We need to distinguish our tags key from their value, and the place we can do that is in our [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) stage. The [`$setDifference`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/#exp._S_setDifference) and [`$setIntersection`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIntersection/#exp._S_setIntersection) operators respectively let us return an array of elements that appear in the first but not in the second array "tagvalue" and and array of element that appear in all of the input sets here "tagKeys".

The [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/#exp._S_map) operator here returns an array of key/value pairs.

Since "tagKeys" and "tagvalue" are array you will need to deconstruct those array and  using the [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind) operator. From there you need to [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) your documents and use the [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/#grp._S_push) accumulator operator which return the newly "tags" array that you can use to update you documents.

Last but not least you need to [`$unset`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/#up._S_unset) the "tagKeys" field in your documents because it is no longer needed. You can always retrieve the "tagKeys" list using the [`.distinct()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) method:

```js
db.collection.distinct('tagsKeys')
```

---

From [MongoDB 3.2](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/3.2/#mongo-shell-and-crud-api) the [`Bulk()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/#Bulk) API and its associated methods are deprecated you will need to use the [`db.collection.bulkWrite()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/3.2-reference/#db.collection.bulkWrite) method.

So this is how it can be done:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": { 
        "element": { 
            "$map": {
                "input": "$tags", 
                "as": "tag", 
                "in": {
                    "value": { "$setDifference": [ "$$tag", "$tagKeys" ] }, 
                    "key": { "$setIntersection": [ "$$tag", "$tagKeys" ] } 
                }
            }
        }
    }}, 
    { "$unwind": "$element" }, 
    { "$unwind": "$element.key" }, 
    { "$unwind": "$element.value" }, 
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": "$_id", 
        "tags": {
            "$push": {
                "tagKey": "$element.key", 
                "value": "$element.value"
            }
        }
    }}
]).forEach(function(doc) { 
    var operation = {
        updateOne: { 
            filter: { '_id': doc._id },
            update: { 
                '$set': { 'tags': doc.tags }, 
                '$unset': { 'tagKeys': '' }
            }
        }
    }; 
    operations.push(operation); 
})

db.collection.bulkWrite(operations)
```